# Local/Remote ls

Tags: shell, ssh, ls, remote

I want to grab relevant lines out of an SNMP logger in real-time and move them over to my application server for checking. The second half is fine, `scp` is doing the trick. The first half is causing me some grief.

What I want to do is check the three latest log files for the relevant messages. 
So I'd do:
`` [user@SNMPServer]$ cd /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/; files=`ls -t | grep -m 3 trap.csv`; echo $files ``

> `trap.csv trap.csv.2019-05-31_07_00_01 trap.csv.2019-05-31_06_00_01`

Which is great, because I then plan to:

`[user@SNMPServer]$ grep $ipAddress $files`

Which again, works fine when I run it on the SNMP server.

When I do it from my VM However,
`` admin@alarmux:~$sudo ssh p210243@192.75.110.40 "cd /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/; files=`ls -t | grep -m 3 trap.csv`; echo $files" ``

I get this output:
`assets
bash: testerlog: command not found
bash: count.txt: command not found`

These are the `ls -t` results from my VM's home directory, not the remote one. 
Am I missing escape characters somewhere?

Comment: remove double tile for `files`

Comment: Sorry I should've noted this - they're only there to keep Stack's formatting consistent. If I single tilde them they become plaintext. Edit: Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backquotes and `$( … )` interpolate inside double quotes.  Use single quotes and it will work.

```
sudo ssh p210243@192.75.110.40 'cd /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/; files=`ls -t | grep -m 3 trap.csv`; echo $files'
```

Or avoid the subshell altogether with xargs:

```
sudo ssh p210243@192.75.110.40 'ls -td /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/* | grep -m 3 trap.csv | xargs grep '$ipAddress
```

Comment: Thank you, xargs works very well. To suggest an edit I would include the `cd` in that line as well since the xargs grep won't work without the full path. Will accept the answer once the timer is up! (2 min or so.)

Comment: oh right.  Adding `/*` to the ls and `-d` yields full paths in the output; edited.

Comment: @KuboMD why do you want a `cd` in the first place? Why not just `files=$(ls -t /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/ | grep -m 3 trap.csv)`?

Comment: @terdon It's very clear you're a much more experienced user than I am. As a beginner, there's no particular reason for the thing you pointed out in your comments. In the future I would suggest that you share your knowledge in the form of statements rather than questions, as they come off as being condescending which deters new users. For example "Just FYI, you don't need to `cd at all ..."

Comment: @OhMyGoodness Quick Q: when I use the xargs solution and try to pipe the output into a file which is `~/trapFolder/$hostname` I get the `~/trapFolder/` is a directory error. Any advice? Looks like: ```ssh p210243@192.75.110.40 'ls -t /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/* | grep -m 3 trap.csv | xargs grep $3 > ~/trapFolder/$2'``` 
($3 is IP $2 is hostname)

Comment: @KuboMD `$2` and `$3` are inside single quotes, that means they'll be resolved on the remote end, where they are not defined.  You need to have them outside of single quotes, so that the local end gets to resolve them: `'ls -td /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/* | grep -m 3 trap.csv | xargs grep '$3' > ~/trapFolder/'$2`

Comment: @KuboMD my apologies, I didn't mean to come across as condescending. I thought there might be a specific reason why you were doing this (the `sudo shh` might make sense if the ssh key is only available for root for some reason and the `cd` might make sense if you didn't want the full path to be included in the results). I was asking to see what your reason was so I could perhaps offer an alternative. In any case, thank you for letting me know how that came across since I really didn't mean to be condescending.

Comment: @terdon It's alright, really! I just know it's a big problem with the stackOverflow community and thank you for being receptive toward it. I do appreciate your input. Regarding your Q's: yes, my key is for the root user rather than `admin` and to be honest the `cd` was just me guessing my way through things at first. I've adopted the `ls -td /dir/*` approach to save me from the cd command. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

With the `zsh` shell, the three files with the most recent modification timestamp, with filenames matching `*trap.cvs` in the `/var/opt/OV/log/nnm` directory, would be had with the pattern

```
/var/opt/OV/log/nnm/*trap.cvs(.om[1,3])
```

where `(...)` modifies the behaviour of the preceding pattern.  `.` selects only regular files (not directory names etc.) and `om` orders by decreasing modification timestamp.  The `[1,3]` returns the first three matches only (or less if there are fewer matches).

So if you have the `zsh` shell installed on the remote machine, you would be able to do

```
ssh p210243@192.75.110.40 zsh -c 'grep -wF "$1" /var/opt/OV/log/nnm/*trap.cvs(.om[1,3])' zsh "$ipAddress"
```

This would launch `grep` to look for the IP address kept in `$ipAddress` in the three most recently modified files on the remote system.

The flags used with `grep` makes it use string comparisons rather than regular expression matches (that's `-F`), and it requires that the matching string is a full word (that's `-w`; so that `123.123.123.123` is not matched by `23.123.123.1`).